# Desktop Application like FlipBoard(Content Collector - Magazine format)

Tags: gratis, desktop-client

I'm looking for a Desktop Application that offers the same functionality as [FlipBoard](https://flipboard.com) for mobiles, which is like a personal magazine that lets you easily read content from your favorite topics(FlipBoard afaik scans a variety of social-networks and sites for that) and create your own selection of those topics.
To be more precise, this application should:

- Be able to choose your favorite topics and **preview** articles - posts(content in general) from those topics
- Integrate your social networks to be able to read news-feed from them inside the app.
- Flip through available content(FlipBoard jumps between articles with a simple touch)
- Be free of charge
- Cross-platform would be welcomed(Although I'm more interested in Win7 and/or LinuxMint)

Comment: How does flipboard differ from an RSS feed aggregator? Or is it the same thing?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm not sure if it is just an RSS feed aggregator, seems like it, what makes it different though I think is the ability to follow magazines(collection of feeds) from another users. Hope I helped!